# Spring Data DTO Projection with @ManyToMany field

Tags: java, spring, kotlin, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I've a `User` Entity that contains this field:

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "FAVORITE_TAGS", joinColumns = arrayOf(JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID")), inverseJoinColumns = arrayOf(JoinColumn(name = "TAG_ID")))
    @BatchSize(size = 24)
    val favoriteTags: MutableSet<Tag>? = null
```

And i defined the following DTO:

```
data class UserProfileDto(
        ...
        val favoriteTags: MutableSet<Tag>?,
        ...
): UserDto()
```

Finally, this is one of the `UserRepository` methods (DTO dynamic projection):

```
fun <T: UserDto> findByUsername(username: String, type: Class<T>): T?
```

The problem is that when i call `userRepository.findByUsername("username", UserProfileDto::class.java)`, i get the following exception:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Unable to locate appropriate constructor on class [com.cillariodelsanto.socialnotes.entity.dto.UserProfileDto]. Expected arguments are: 
    java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, double, long, com.cillariodelsanto.socialnotes.entity.Tag, long, long, long, long [select new com.cillariodelsanto.socialnotes.entity.dto.UserProfileDto(generatedAlias0.username, generatedAlias0.name, generatedAlias0.userPicPath, generatedAlias0.averageScore, generatedAlias0.documentsRatingsCount, favoriteTags, generatedAlias0.documentsCount, generatedAlias0.favoriteDocumentsCount, generatedAlias0.followingCount, generatedAlias0.followersCount) from com.cillariodelsanto.socialnotes.entity.User as generatedAlias0 left join generatedAlias0.favoriteTags as favoriteTags where generatedAlias0.username=:param0]
```

The problem is the `MutableSet` (i've tried with `Collection` and `Set` too, but the result was the same). Is there a way to fix it?

I know that using the interfaces instead of the DTOs would resolve the problem, but i'd like to know if it is possible to achieve the same result using the DTOs. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Does it still give that error if you supply default arguments to all of the data class parameters?

Comment: Unfortunately yes, I already tried.

Comment: By the way, if I replace MutableSet<Tag> with Tag it works. He can not map the MutableSet. Using the interface projection with the same example works like a charm, but i cannot understand why.

Comment: Your problem is that your Entity class is giving Spring some very specific instructions on how to resolve that Set. It's telling it where to find the data and how to map it to the object. However, your DTO model doesn't contain that information, so Spring doesn't know how to make the complex mapping.

At a glance, that looks like the issue at hand here.